# Why doesn't my new SFTP user work under a different directory?

Tags: linux, debian, shell, ftp, sftp

I am trying to create a new SFTP account for my server. When I follow these instructions **exactly**, then everything works fine: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

I can connect with the `guestuser` user via `sftp`, browse my home directory, and go one level up from `incoming` into `/sftp/guestuser`.

I can even change the `ChrootDirectory` value in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to specifically be `/sftp/guestuser`, instead of implementing the `%u` parameter. So hardcoded directory names therefore work fine.

But from that point, if all I do is change the `ChrootDirectory` of my `sftpusers` group to my actual website's directory on `/var/www/www.example.com`, then I cannot connect via the `sftp` command on that user anymore. The shell outputs:

> Connection to www.example.com closed by remote host. Couldn't read
>   packet: Connection reset by peer

I definitely did:

1. Make sure I had the `incoming` folder in my `/var/www/www.example.com` directory
2. Set the ownership of both `/var/www/www.example.com` and `/var/www/www.example.com/incoming` to `guestuser:sftpusers`
3. Tried setting the home directory of user to `/` by doing `usermod guestuser -d /`

The `/sftp/guestuser` directory (the one with which it worked) is in the ownership of `root:root`, so the fact that the permissions of `/var/www` are on `root:root` should not matter(?)

How come I cannot change the home directory of my new SFTP user?

**UPDATE**

I can change the directory to:

- `/sftp`
- `/`
- `/var`
- `/var/www`

Those all work. But as soon as go one more under `/var/www`, like `/var/www/test`, it doesn't work. I've tried removing the dots from the original directory name that was `www.example.com`, but it didn't make a difference.

It's not about a limit on the number of subdirectory levels either, because `/sftp/guestuser/incoming` also worked. Testing it with a new directory `/web/www.example.com` did not.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've managed to pinpoint the cause. The directory that i define as the `ChrootDirectory` for the user must be owned by `root`.

If i want my user to be able to upload stuff (which obviously he won't be able to do in a root-owned one), then i need to create a subdirectory in there, and set that directory as his home via the `-d` parameter when creating or editing the user.

If at any point the ownership is changed so that the `ChrootDirectory` is owned by that user that is trying to ftp into it, the `broken pipe` message will appear again. Changing the ownership back to `root`, and the user can connect again.

Comment: The problem is that the user will have to do a cd to his folder before uploading. Would be nice if they can just login and upload immediately. How about making the folder group writeable, owned by root and adding user to the group?

Comment: I changed the ownership of folder to root and made it writeable/executable by all. Still no luck. Cannot make it the ChrootDirectory.